# How to repeat failed tape backup attempt in DPM 2007?

Tags: backup, scdpm

How do you repeat a scheduled backup of a protection group if the first backup attempt failed (e.g. if there were no tapes in the library, or if there was an intermittent failure in the library or drive).

I know that you can force a backup of single protected element in the console by selecting "Create Recovery Point - Tape" in the context menu, but how do you force a tape backup of a whole protection group?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>DISCLAIMER!! These are cleaned up versions of what I actually use, I have not had a need to test these cleaned versions, so they probably contain an error or two. My apologies! Please comment/edit/anything if do find a mistake so others don't have to fix it again.</sub>

1. If you still have the error in Monitoring -> Alerts, you can right click it an select Resume Backups.
2. If you want to create a new backup (what's currently on the protected server)
   Open the DPM Shell and paste this script:

   ```
   param([string] $dpmname, [string] $pgname)

   if(!$dpmname) {
       $dpmname = Read-Host "DPM server"
   }
   if(!$pgname) {
    $pgname =  Read-Host "Protection Group Friendly Name"
   }
   Write-Output "Creating Tape Recovery Point"
   trap{"Error in execution... $_";break}
   &{
       Write-Output "Getting protection group $pgname in $dpmname..."
       $clipg = Get-ProtectionGroup $dpmname | where { $_.FriendlyName -eq $pgname}
       if($clipg -eq $abc) {
           Throw "No PG found"
       }
       Write-Output "Getting DS from PG $pgname..."
       $backupds = @(Get-Datasource $clipg)
       foreach ($ds in $backupds) {
           Write-Output "Creating Recovery point for $ds..."
           $j = New-RecoveryPoint -Datasource $ds -Tape -ProtectionType LongTerm
           $jobtype = $j.jobtype
           Write-Output "$jobtype Job has been triggerred..."
       }
   }
   ```

   It will ask for the name of the Server and Protection Group to be backed up.
3. If you want to copy a disk backup to tape media (for the whole protection group)
   Open the DPM Shell and paste this script:

   ```
   param([string] $dpmserver, [string] $pgname, [datetime] $rpdt, [int] $tapeoption)
   $searchminutes = 10
   $libraryindex = 0
   if(!$dpmserver) {
       $dpmserver = Read-Host "DPM server"
   }
   if(!$pgname) {
       $pgname =  Read-Host "Protection Group Friendly Name"
   }
   if(!$rpdt) {
       $rpdt = Read-Host "Time of existing Recovery Point"
       if (($rpdt -as [DateTime]) -ne $null) {
           $rpdt = [DateTime]::Parse($rpdt)
       } else {
           Write-Host 'You did not enter a valid date/time!'
       }
   }
   $rpdt.AddMinutes($serachminutes / 2)
   if(!$tapeoption) {
       $tapeoption = Read-Host "Tape Option: 0 = Compress, 1 = Encrypt, 2 = Neither"
   }
   Write-Host "Creating $backupoption Recovery Point"
   trap{"Error in execution... $_";break}
   &{
       Write-Host "-Getting protection group $pgname in $dpmserver..."
       $clipg = Get-ProtectionGroup $dpmserver | where { $_.FriendlyName -eq $pgname}
       if(!$clipg) {
           Throw "No PG found!"
       }
       Write-Host "-Getting libraries on $dpmserver..."
       $libraries = @(Get-DPMLibrary -DPMServerName $dpmserver)
       if(!$libraries) {
           Throw "No Tape Drive/Library found!"
       }
       Write-Output "--Getting Data Sources from Protection Group $pgname..."
       $backupds = @(Get-Datasource $clipg)
       foreach ($ds in $backupds) {
           Write-Host -NoNewline "---$ds... "
           $rps = @(Get-RecoveryPoint -Datasource $ds) | Where { (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.RepresentedPointInTime -End $rpdt).TotalMinutes -lt $searchminutes }
           Write-Host -NoNewline "RPs Found... "
           foreach ($rp in $rps) {
               Write-Host -NoNewLine "Creating Job... "
               $j = Copy-DPMTapeData -RecoveryPoint $rp -SourceLibrary $libraries[$libraryindex] -TapeLabel "asdf" -TapeOption $tapeoption -TargetLibrary $libraries[$libraryindex]
               Write-Host "Job: $j.status"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: If you know what you're doing, the basic structure of the above script is:

   ```
   $libs = @(Get-DPMLibrary -DPMServerName $dpmname)
   $pg = @(Get-ProtectionGroup -DPMServerName @dpmname)
   $ds = @(Get-Datasouce -ProtectionGroup $pg[n])
   $rp = @(GetRecoverPoint -Datasource $ds[n])
   Copy-DPMTapeData -RecoveryPoint $pr[n] -SourceLibrary $libs[n] -TapeLabel "Whatever" -TapeOption $x $TargetLibrary $libs[n]
   ```